# Use regex in c# to remove specific combination of characters

Tags: c#, regex, string

I would like to keep in my string the following characters:

- numeric characters : 1-9
- alpha characters : aA-zA
- only apostroph character surrounded by alphanumeric characters, ie "x'x" where x belongs to alphanumeric characters group.

At this point, I am able to keep all the alphanumeric characters. The problem is with the apostroph character, I am keeping all the apostroph whereas I would like to keep only the ones surrounded by alphanumeric characters. This is my code :

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9' -]");
string newString = rgx.Replace(oldString, "");
```

Example : For this string `"abc'd1*%'"`, I would like to get `"abc'd1"`.

Comment: Why you want to keep `abc`?

Comment: As I told you I need to keep all the alphanumeric characters, but that's not the problem. The question is how to indicate to the regex to keep only apostroph surrounded by alphanumeric characters and not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below regex and then replace the matched characters with an empty string.

```
@"(?<![A-Za-z])'|'(?![A-Za-z])|[^A-Za-z0-9']"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tQ4oW4/5)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<![A-Za-z])'` Matches all the single quotes which is not preceded by an alphabet.
- `|` OR
- `'(?![A-Za-z])` Matches all the single quotes which is not followed by an alphabet. So theses two patterns fails to match the single quotes which is preceded and followed by a alphabet.
- `|` OR
- `[^A-Za-z0-9']` From the remaining string, this pattern would match any character but not of alphanumeric or single quotes.

**Code:**

```
string str = "abc'd1*%'";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<![A-Za-z])'|'(?![A-Za-z])|[^A-Za-z0-9']", "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/E7whOr)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and especially for the explainations.

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9 -]+|(?<=[a-zA-Z])'(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/13

Answer (score 0):

If you are matching whitespace, try this:

```
[\w\s-]+|(?<=[\w\s])'(?=[\w\s])
```

If no whitespace, try this:

```
[\w-]+|(?<=[\w])'(?=[\w])
```